# Simple function causing very high gas fees solidity

Tags: solidity, gas

Hello everyone i just recently dpeloyed my first main net contract.

Now on solidity and locally all the fees looked good and it was quite minimal. I have this function which creates a bet and just changes some state. The minimum version of it looks like:

```
struct Bet {
    address creator;
    address taker;
    uint256 amount;
    uint256 targetPrice;
    uint256 endDate;
    bool isAbove;
    bool isCompleted;
}

mapping(uint256 => Bet) public bets;

function createBet(uint256 _targetPrice, uint256 _endDate, bool _isAbove) external payable whenNotPaused() {
    require(msg.value > 0, "Must bet a positive amount");
    require(msg.value >= minimumBet, "Bet must be larger than the minimum limit");
    require(msg.value <= maximumBet, "Bet must be smaller than the maximum limit");
    require(_endDate > block.timestamp, "End date must be in the future");

    bets[betCount] = Bet({
        creator: msg.sender,
        taker: address(0),
        amount: msg.value,
        targetPrice: _targetPrice,
        endDate: _endDate,
        isAbove: _isAbove,
        isCompleted: false
    });

    emit BetCreated(betCount, msg.sender, msg.value, _targetPrice, _endDate, _isAbove);
    betCount++;
}
```

Seems quite straight forward I think. Now when i create a bet with .01 eth. The gas fee will end up being .045-.09, ending the total cost near .02. (this is what the winner would get so ofcourse makes it useless to do).

It is however the first ever contract interaction, is it possible that the first one will cost more since it will create the public bets map? Could anyone give me some insights?

Thank you!!

Comment: High gas like that is usually a failure to estimate gas, telling you the tx will revert. Have you used a debugger to look at why it would fail? Take the hex data from metamask and enter it into the simulation page on tenderly.co for a relatively simple way to debug.

Comment: @Maka It's not failing, nothing crazy high but around .008 gas

Comment: Yes apologies, I see your question now. 
Someone should know without experimentation, but could you simulate on a fork across two transactions and just look at the gas consumption across steps?